# Does a data race exist if you are only reading the shared data?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm writing a program that will be multi threaded. The threads will all read from the shared data, but not write to it at all. Does a data race exist in this case? I don't think it does, since I'm not doing any writing to the shared data, but I wanted to ask and make sure.

Comment: which platform are you working on? When is the data written? Does the underlying memory model ensure that at the time one thread is reading it, it will not use its own cache (or it has an up to date value) and that the writing end will have flushed its cache to the main memory?

Comment: C++ on windows right now. The data is established in memory before the threads act on it and the data never changes during the program execution. The data is stored in std::vector

Answer (score 0):

If you write to shared data before creating thread pool A and never again after that, thread pool A can read from the the same shared data concurrently.

Creating a thread induces a memory barrier and therefore the data is guaranteed to be synchronized with thread pool A and a data race does not exist.